# How to remove query string in url with vue spa application?

Tags: vue.js, redirect, vuejs2, vue-router

a Vue2 application e.g. (`http://www.example.com`). two routes ('/', '/dashboard'), and '/' will be redirected to '/dashboard'.

1. Now another sso system (e.g. `http://www.sso.com`) send a redirect to `http://www.example.com?token=xxxxxx`,
2. then the browser execute the redirect, the Vue router recog the route as '/' and
3. then redirect to '/dashboard' according to router settings.

But now, the url in browser address bar is like `http://www.example.com?token=xxxxxx#/dashboard`, though the application works I want to remove the query string '?token=xxxxxx' from the address bar but failed.

I try two ways:

1. set window.location.search=null, but the '?' sign is still in the url.
2. use navigation guard next('/dashboard') when 'to' is '/', also failed.

Could someone kindly give a helping hand please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the dashboard component use router.push to remove the query string.

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  created: function () {
    let self = this;
    self.$router.push('/dashboard');
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @shahidiqbal, will try it tomorrow, does that push trigger 'created' function repeatedly?

Comment: No it will run only once when you navigate to the /dashboard route.